# Why do we connect pins 2 and 3 on APM to enable PPM

Tags: quadcopter, uav, ardupilot

Why is it necessary to connect signal pins 2 and 3 via jumper on an APM2.8 board to enable PPM.
I am using flysky  fs-ia6b receiver with the APM mentioned above.
Pins 2 and 3 control pitch and throttle respectively so how does shorting these two pins helps with PPM and why not roll (pin1) and yaw (pin4) require such shorting.

Comment: Hi @A.Sinha, can you elaborate on this question?  One line questions are rarely sufficient.  It's a good idea to include details of what you want to understand, what you've researched so far, what you found & what you expected to find. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: On stack exchange, comments are not intended for extended discussions, they are for helping to improve questions and answers. Comments are distracting, so we try to keep them to a minimum. They should be considered ephemeral, any comment which no longer actively helps to improve a question or answer may be deleted at any time to *tidy up* a post. For extended discussion on a question or answer, please use [chat]. Also, please try to *[be nice](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/behavior)*.

Comment: The pulse position modulation (PPM Encoder) is part of the Ardupilot Mega (APM) board to control drones. According to the quickstart guide, the pins have to connected before the first run. quote “The encoder also detects the loss of RC signal in the RC receiver” Vaswani, Vishal, et al. "Modular Quadrotor MAVs." (2014).

Comment: @ManuelRodriguez What is the purpose of connecting the two pins.

Comment: @A.Sinha - Could you please *edit your question* to include more details? This has been requested several times now. As jsotola correctly mentioned, jumpers are used to make configurations that are both non-volatile and user accessible with no special tools. Beyond that, the functionality that is enabled is determined by whatever the software is programmed to do. When I try to look online to help answer your question, I had to start by Googling "APM board," because your question doesn't link it. There seem to be several options - plane or copter? Several versions, several suppliers, etc.

Comment: Your question seems clear enough to me, but you're making it very hard for us to help you because your question doesn't include enough detail. Ultimately, the answer is going to be to look at the source code for the project and see what portion of the software is referencing those pins. If you can look at the source code then you can answer the question yourself. *I understand this may be challenging,* and I'm willing to help, but I don't know the manufacturer or version, or where to find a source code repository, etc. *If you can post that information* then answering becomes much easier.

Comment: Finally, it is totally possible that source code is not publicly available. If this is the case then it's not possible for any outsider to divine what the purpose is. Maybe it's a safety check, or some version of [IP protection](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/120265), or maybe it's grounding the serial port so you can't write to the device while it's in flight - could be anything. We either need a link to the source code or enough information regarding what you have that we can the source code. If the source code isn't available then again you need to contact the manufacturer.

Comment: @Chuck I have updated my question. Please do let me know if any more info is required.